# I have using three libraries for my app and gradle is taking so much time to debug

Tags: android, gradle, jvm

I had used this libraries
 1. GestureImageView
 2. squarecamera
 3. daimajia.slider

Gradle is taking so much time, I had done this to make gradle faster.
http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html

Even though I had set in app gradle dexOptions{incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
},
Please Corrent me If I am wrong, and please suggest me to get gradle faster.

Answer (score 0):

using local gradle . is Prefernces->build->gralde , select Use local gradle distribution and Offline work. and maybe your android studio version is low,please update. and  use JRebel.. some..   You need to upgrade your computer。。

Comment: I have mac 2.3 Ghz processor 5 Gb RAM with installation of  jdk 1.8 and android studio 2.2.3, apart from that I had done that as in Preference to set offline gradle. But I would like use JRebel. Anything else I need to look?